# Join two files in Pyspark without using sparksql/dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have two files customer and sales like below

Customer :

> cu_id name   region city   state
>    1  Rahul  ME     Vizag  AP
>    2  Raghu  SE     HYD    TS
>    3  Rohith ME     BNLR   KA

Sales:

> sa_id sales  country
>   2 100000 IND
>   3 230000 USA
>   4 240000 UK

Both the files are \t delimited.
I want to join both the files based on the cu_id from customer and sa_id from sales using pyspark with out using sparksql/dataframes.

your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use the `join` methods that Spark has to offer regarding workings with `RDD`'s.

You can do something like:

```
customerRDD = sc.textFile("customers.tsv").map(lambda row: (row.split('\t')[0], "\t".join(row.split('\t')[1:])))
salesRDD = sc.textFile("sales.tsv").map(lambda row: (row.split('\t')[0], "\t".join(row.split('\t')[1:])))

joinedRDD = customerRDD.join(salesRDD)
```

And you will get a new `RDD` that contains the only joined records from both customer and sales files.